# Blackberry UI - how to embed link within text

Tags: blackberry, java-me

I am making a BlackBerry app, supporting OS 4.5 and later, where I want to embed some links within a line of text on the screen. Like this -

text text text [link1](http://www.google.com) text text [link2](http://www.google.com) text

How do I do it? Tried using 4 seperate ActiveRichTextFields but the problem is how do I make link1 n link2 focus-sable as a word? setChangeListener(this) and setFocusListener(this.getFocusListener()) doesnt seem to do the trick. And how do I capture the click event on the links to redirect it to the webpages?

Comment: I think it might be possible to implement a custom UI field such as RichTextField which will render the link like text with normal text, handle focus events, focus movement etc.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [HyperLink](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Implement-advanced-buttons-fields-and-managers/ta-p/488276) example provides By RIM . I think that will surely help you.